# Why we use first class function in Django custom middleware like this?

Tags: python, django-middleware

It's a custom middleware code:

```py
def my_middleware(get_response):
    print('One time initialization')

    def my_function(request):
        print('Its before view function')
        response = get_response(request)
        print('Its after view function')
        return response
    return my_function
```

Comment: What alternative would you propose, though?

Comment: Nothing, but I keen to know.

Comment: Explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware